# In-place upgrade from Windows 7 to specific Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

There are still some Windows 7 machines on our network, some of which can be easily reinstalled, some of which can't because of specific software and settings.

I've tried to do an in-place upgrade of one of the test machines to test the process. It worked very well, but upgraded to the latest version of Windows 10 (1909), which was expected.

However, due to certain restrictions (again, specific software), we are only allowed to install Windows 10 up to and including version 1709. The software is not yet validated on Windows 1709 (and without validation of the company, there is no support).

How can I do an in-place upgrade to Windows 1709?

Comment: Download a Windows 10 1709 ISO.  However, fair warning, 1709 isn’t supported.  You will be told this unless you have a WSUS configuration

Comment: Windows 10 V1909 is already from last year and a new version will be out within 2020. Best to upgrade the software that does not work or change to different software. The Windows update process never stops.

Comment: @John I understand what you are saying, but the software we're using is tied to hardware (costing several millions). Basically you're tied to both the software, the vendor and their rules as soon as you enter a contract, there is no other software to switch to. Frankly, being able to switch from Windows 7 to Windows 10 is a moral victory - there's still a lot of hardware which requires Windows XP, unfortunately.

Comment: For the machines that need access to this software (I hope it is not everyone), try a different approach.  Set up a Windows 7 virtual machine, even an XP virtual machine, and run the software that way.

Comment: Why bother since 1709 is no longer supported just like 7, just stick with W7. I see no victory by upgrading, just a waste of time and possible issues with 10

Comment: @John That would mean setting up a VM for each and every computer as well as keeping a computer running for Windows 10 for each user, which is overkill.

Comment: @Moab Windows 10 1709 is in fact still supported for us, and having all machines on a similar (or identical) version is a big bonus (especially for support).

Comment: V1709 will be gone soon and V2004 will be out before this year ends. Windows 10 now needs to be on every computer because all predecessors get ever more out of support. So Windows 10 is not overkill. Virtual Machines may appear to be overkill, but there are limited options here

Comment: @John I'm not saying Windows 10 is overkill, I'm saying running a Windows 10 machine as well as a virtual machine for every user is overkill. We want to get rid of Windows 7 as soon as possible, but because we're tied to vendor support, we're stuck with a maximum version of Windows 10 1709 (further versions are not yet supported, but will become available in the future).